# why isn't google apps script sending invitations

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

The Google Apps script ran in a spreadsheet below and everything worked fine except sending the invites. Using `sendInvites:true` the event is created in the calendar and the guests are added but no email is sent. I have tried it without using the `var advancedArgs` and same results.

```
 if (eventImported  != EVENT_IMPORTED && title != "") {  // Prevents importing duplicates
    var cal = CalendarApp.openByName('calendarname');
    var advancedArgs = {description: details, location: cust, guests:guestlist, sendInvites:true};

    cal.createEvent("10% Complete-->"+title, startDate, endDate, {description: details, location: cust, guests:guestlist, sendInvites:true});
    sheet.getRange(startcolumn + i, 9).setValue(EVENT_IMPORTED);
```

Comment: Were you able to find out the cause?

Answer (score 2):

The error must be somewhere else, I tested your code in this simplified version and I received the invitation as expected. (I use this option a lot in many scripts without any issue)

Could you show how you get your guest list ? is it a comma separated email list as specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendar?hl=fr-FR#createEvent) ?

```
function testcal(){
    var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()
    var advancedArgs = {description: 'details', location: 'here', guests:'serge@xxx.com', sendInvites:true};// change the email adress to a valid one that you have access to (but not your email adress of course !
    var startDate = new Date();// now
    var endDate = new Date(startDate.setHours(10));// at 10 AM, change this according to time of the day when you (eventually) test it
    cal.createEvent("test to delete", startDate, endDate, advancedArgs);
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I also want to send google calendar event but getting error in `Calendar.Events.patch()` method, you can find the whole question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75634093/error-sending-google-calendar-invite-using-google-apps-script

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may be being rate limited somewhere. I had a similar problem and sending emails would work sporadically. I was polling a group of users calendars and when I found enough available at a certain time I would send the invitation to all.

In frustration I added:

Utilities.sleep(30000);

just before I create the event and it works reliably now. You can probably get away with less time, but mine runs on trigger at 2am so I don't care.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that **no event invitation is sent to my *own email address*** (although the event is added to my calendar). But event invitations are correctly sent to other guests.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I also want to send google calendar event but getting error in `Calendar.Events.patch()` method, you can find the whole question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75634093/error-sending-google-calendar-invite-using-google-apps-script

Answer (score -1):

Try Out:
  var advancedArgs = {description: details, location: cust,
                      guests:guestlist, sendInvites:"TRUE"};

Comment: argument IS boolean, not a string. see [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendar#createEvent)