# Error sending google calendar invite using Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, events, google-calendar-api

I want to send a Google calendar invite using the google apps script but I am encountering an error in the last line of the following code snippet:

```
function testnotification(){
         var calendarId = "####";
         var eventId = "###";
         var email = ""###@gmail.com
         addGuestAndSendEmail(calendarId,eventId,email)
       }
    
    
      function addGuestAndSendEmail(calendarId, eventId, newGuest) {
    
      var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);    
      var event = calendar.getEventById(eventId);
      var attendees = [];
      attendees.push({email: newGuest});
      var resource = { attendees: attendees };
      var args = { sendUpdates: "all" };
    
      calendar.createEvent.patch(resource, calendarId, eventId, args);
    }
```

I have modified last line from `Calendar.Events.patch(event, calendar, event.id, args);` to       `calendar.createEvent.patch(resource, calendarId, eventId, args)`, however when I run, it says:

> calendar.createEvent.patch is not a function

I reviewed stackoverflow questions ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123667/sending-calendar-invites-to-non-google-accounts-via-google-apps-script) , [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53530248/send-calendar-invites-based-on-google-form-submission)) but couldn't find a way. [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) proposed the following answer, when I ran this script:

```
function testNotification(){

         var calendarId = "###";
         var eventId = "###";
         var email = "###@gmail.com"
            addGuestAndSendEmail(calendarId,eventId,email)
       }
           
        function addGuestAndSendEmail(calendarId, eventId, newGuest) {
           Calendar.Events.patch({ attendees: [{ email: newGuest }] }, calendarId, eventId, { sendUpdates: "all" });
    }
```

I received the following **error**:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.patch failed
> with error: Not Found

This calendar is shared with me however, I have the following permissions to this calendar:

[image: Permission]

Comment: From discussion with the owner of this question, it was found that when the calendar IDs of shared calendar and OP's own calendar are used with the Calendar API, the same error like `API call to calendar.events.patch failed with error: Not Found` occurs. In this case, it is considered that the reason for the current issue depends on the setting of Google Workspace belonging to the owner of this question. I think that the modified script is correct.

Comment: But, if the calendar cannot be accessed from Calendar API, I'm worried that an error of `Not Found` occurs. Although I could understand your 1st issue, unfortunately, I cannot resolve your 2nd issue In this case, my answer has already not been useful. So, I have to delete my answer. I apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: Can we somehow make it work using: `CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId)`?

Comment: @Tanaike, thankfully your script is working fine now, you can repost your answer or let me know and I will repost it,

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If you think that our discussions in my answer will be useful for other users, I can reopen my answer.

Comment: Sure, please do it, I am removing my answer

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I reopened my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `calendar.createEvent.patch(resource, calendarId, eventId, args);` is not correct. I think that the reason for your current issue of `calendar.createEvent.patch is not a function` is due to this. If you want to achieve your goal, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your `addGuestAndSendEmail` is modified.

```js
function addGuestAndSendEmail(calendarId, eventId, newGuest) {
  Calendar.Events.patch({ attendees: [{ email: newGuest }] }, calendarId, eventId, { sendUpdates: "all" });
}
```

- When the values of `calendarId, eventId, newGuest` are valid values, an email is sent to `newGuest`.

#### Note:

- Before you test this script, [please enable Calendar API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

#### Reference:

- [Events: patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch)

### Added:

About your 2nd issue of `API call to calendar.events.patch failed with error: Not Found` using my proposed script,

- In the case that the permission of calendar is "See only free/busy (hide details)" and "See all event details", an error like `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.patch failed with error: Forbidden` occurs.
- In the case that the permission of the calendar is "Make changes to events", no error occurs.
- In the case that the permission of calendar is "Make changes and manage sharing", no error occurs.
- In the case that the invalid value is used as `calendarId`, an error like `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.patch failed with error: Not Found` occurs.

  - It seems that this error message is the same with your error message.

From your updated question of `I have also updated permission screenshot in my question, please review it`, I noticed that your permission is "Make changes and manage sharing". In this case, I think that the script works. But even when you change the permission from "Make changes and manage sharing" to "Make changes to events", the same error of `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.patch failed with error: Not Found` occurs. In this case, I would like to recommend confirming the calendar ID again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer however it shows following error:
`API call to calendar.events.patch failed with error: Not Found`

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. From `API call to calendar.events.patch failed with error: Not Found`, I'm worried that you have still disabled Calendar API. How about this? And also, from `API call to calendar.events.patch failed with error: Not Found`, I'm worried that you miscopied my script. How about this? In my proposed script `Calendar.Events.patch`. Please confirm it again. If you cannot understand my comment, can you provide your Google Apps Script project for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Roomi By the way, when I tested my proposed script using the sample values of `calendarId, eventId, newGuest` by enabling Calendar API, no error occurs. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: just to let you know, this is not my primary caldendar, this is shared calendar to which I have access. could that be the reason, I also updated my question with your script, I have already enabled calendar api, thank you

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. I understood your question as you wanted to resolve your issue of `calendar.createEvent.patch is not a function`. I answered your this question. But in your reply, in your reply, you say `this is not my primary caldendar, this is shared calendar to which I have access.`. I couldn't notice it from your initial question. I apologize for my poor English skill. In this case, your question has 2 issues. One is your wrong script. And, another is the issue of permission.

Comment: @Roomi About your 1st issue, I think that my proposed script can be used. About your 2nd issue, in this case, it is required to confirm the permission for changing the event to the calendar of `calendarId`. But, I can't know your situation. So, I would like to recommend resolving from your 1st issue. So, please test my proposed script using the valid calendar ID. After you confirmed the script can be used, as the next step, please confirm the permission for the calendar ID of your current issue.

Comment: thank you , I have also updated permission screenshot in my question, please review it

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. From your updated question of `I have also updated permission screenshot in my question, please review it`, I noticed that your permission is "Make changes and manage sharing". So, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. In that case, if my understanding of your situation is correct, I would like to recommend changing the permission.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have changed the permission to  "Make changes to events" and double checked the calendar id, unfortunately still the same error

Comment: @Roomi Sorry. I noticed that I test the wrong script. I will update my answer. Please wait for it.

Comment: @Roomi I have to apologize for my poor skill. I have tested the wrong script. By using the latest script, I tested the script with several situations. By this, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. I guessed that the reason for your current issue is due to the invalid calendar ID. Please confirm your calendar ID again.

Comment: Sorry, same error. I have also added my calendar id in the question,

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. About `Sorry, same error. I have also added my calendar id in the question, `, I think that in this case, you are using an invalid calendar ID. Can you provide the sample calendar ID by hiding the personal information? When the calendar ID is a valid value, the script works with the permission of "Make changes to events" and "Make changes and manage sharing".

Comment: I am using this calendar id: 46fd39be3fc508ac49579b595ba574667a79eecbfdcfaed83cf2af77b401ab@group.calendar.google.com

Comment: The calendar is accessible when I use this : var calendar=CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. About `The calendar is accessible when I use this : var calendar=CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);`, when `Logger.log(CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId))` is run, I think that `null` is shown.

Comment: @Roomi By the way, about `Sorry, same error. I have also added my calendar id in the question`, in this case, when you use your calendar ID with `Logger.log(CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId).getName())`, you can see the correct calendar title can be seen in the log?

Comment: @Roomi And, in your situation, your account is in Google Workspace and you are trying to access a calendar in Google Workspace?

Comment: yes, my account is in google workspace, when I logged it, it showed me correct name which is "UX Reviews", you can also test with the following calendar id:
"46fd39be3fc508ac49579b595ba574667a70c9eecbfdcfaed83cf2af77b401ab@group.calendar.google.com"

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. About `Sorry, same error. I have also added my calendar id in the question`, in this case, when you use your calendar ID with `Logger.log(CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId).getName())`, you can see the correct calendar title can be seen in the log?

Comment: yes, the correct title can be seen when I use logger.log

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. About `yes, my account is in google workspace`, in this case, it is required to confirm your situation to the administrator. Because the calendar might not be able to be accessed by Calendar API. Unfortunately, I cannot know the setting in your situation. I apologize for this. So, first, I would like to recommend confirming whether the script works using valid calendar ID.

Comment: I can access the calendar with getCalendarsById() method

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `I can access the calendar with getCalendarsById() method`, you cannot misunderstand my comment. Please test my script with the calendar ID of your own calendar. If the same error occurs, I'm worried that Calendar API might not be able to be used in your situation. At that time, please confirm about it to your administrator.

Comment: yes, I am having same error even in my own calendar, I have tried it with 2 different google accounts

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. From `yes, I am having same error even in my own calendar`, I think that your 2nd issue is due to the setting of Google Workspace. In this case, I would like to ask about your current issue to your administrator.

Comment: @Roomi I think that from discussion with the owner of this question, it is considered that the reason for the current issue of `API call to calendar.events.patch failed with error: Not Found` depends on the setting of Google Workspace belonging to the owner of this question. I think that the modified script is correct.

Comment: @Roomi But, if the calendar cannot be accessed from Calendar API, I'm worried that an error of `Not Found` occurs. Although I could understand your 1st issue, unfortunately, I cannot resolve your 2nd issue In this case, my answer has already not been useful. So, I have to delete my answer. I apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: Can we send calendar notification by accessing calendar using getCalendarsById()?