# Google Invitation is not sent using Google apps script when I use my personal email address

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-app-invites

Continuation to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75640179/sending-multiple-google-calendar-invites-using-google-apps-script/75640548#75640548), following code snippet is proposed by [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) to send Google calendar invitation email to multiple email addresses simultaneously:

```
function SendMultiple(calendarId, eventId) {
  var newGuests = ["user1@gmail.com", "user2@gmail.com"];
  Calendar.Events.patch({ attendees: newGuests.map(email => ({ email })) }, calendarId, eventId, { sendUpdates: "all" });
}
```

However, when I use my personal email address in the `newGuests` array, it does not send to it, for example:

```
 var newGuests = ["personal@gmail.com","user1@gmail.com", "user2@gmail.com"];
```

It will not send Google calendar invitation to:

> personal@gmail.com

Is it because my email has edit access to the calendar while others do not have? or can we find a way to send emails to this personal email address as well, any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would like to confirm your current situation. When `var newGuests = ["personal@gmail.com","user1@gmail.com", "user2@gmail.com"];` is used, who can get the email from these 3 emails?

Comment: only `user1@gmail.com` and `user2@gmail.com` get the emails

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the invitation was not sent to your personal email account? I've found that such emails do not appear in the Inbox, but you may find the email lurking under "All Mail".

Comment: Yes, I am certain of it, as I just tested it and checked in my personal email under "All Mail", there is no Google calendar notification email

Comment: "Yes, I am certain of it," - OK, worth trying... Who is the "Organiser", and what is their email? For example, when the emails are send to "user1@gmail.com and user2@gmail.com", what is the email address of the sender?

Comment: `personal@gmail.com` is the sender

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, what is the difference between `personal@gmail.com` and `user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com`?

Comment: `personal@gmail.com` is a guest and also has calendar edit access while `user1@gmail.com` and `user2@gmail.com` are just guests added to the calendar by `personal@gmail.com`

Comment: Related topic: [Mark A Guest as organizer in Google calendar event](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/137488/196152)

Comment: no, this is not the solution to this issue

Comment: In your situation, who is the owner of the calendar? By the way, in your situation, if you use Google Workspace, how about confirming the calendar log events at the admin console? I thought that the calendar log events might include the information related to the invitation email. If I misunderstood it, I apologize.

Comment: Calendar owner is someone else and that person shared calendar with me,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the same behavior using Google Apps Script as well as when using the Google Calendar Web UI by doing this:

1. Share a calendar created by *someoneelse@gmail.com* with *personal@gmail.com* and allow  *personal@gmail.com* to manage all calendar events.
2. *someoneelse@gmail.com* creates a calendar event in that calendar.
3. *personal@gmail.com* updates the calendar event attendees and adds their own email (By either clicking the three-dot menu or using Google Apps Script).
4. Email invites are only sent to all other emails besides the user personal@gmail.com

I could find this issue tracker entry where the same behavior was reported but it was confirmed to be an expected behavior: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/235108773#comment6.

Basically, Google is considering the actor of the Event Update request as an Organizer, this would explain why the invites are not sent in this specific scenario. You could create a Feature Request requesting for a feature to be able to send invitation emails to all attendees regardless of the using this link https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/support#developer_product_feedback.

Comment: thank you for your explanation and suggestion, I shall look into it